# change string to date as per the required date Format

Tags: java, date

I have to get a Date in type Date, not in String.
I have this code:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
Date date1 = new Date();
String date = (formatter.format(date1));
// At this point I get the date in correct format i.e  05/24/11

Date todaysDate = (Date)formatter.parse(date);
// But after this I get the date in format : Tue May 24 00:00:00 EDT 2011
// whereas I Want to get the date like above i.e  05/24/11 
// And in type Date, not in type String
```

If anyone could help, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In other words, you want `Date.toString()` to return the same as `DateFormat.format()`? You could just do exactly that:

```
public class MyDate extends Date {
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");

    public String toString() {
        return this.formatter.format(this);
    }
}
```

But do you really want to mix up presentation (date format) with your data?

Comment: thanks for your help ,but i do not need it in String , I want it in Date type , in this method                                      public String toString() {
        return this.formatter.format(this);
    }                                          you are returning String , i need to return Date.     Any suggestions

Comment: Then you're asking the impossible. A `Date` is a `Date`, it's not a `String`. If you want an easy way to output your date, then this solution will work, i.e. MyDate myDate = new MyDate(); System.out.println(myDate);

Comment: Oh! It's for saving to a database... would have been nice to know in the question.

Comment: hi , the date i am getting is like 2011-05-25 00:00:00  after setting format as ("MM/dd/yy");        i there a way to cut down this 00:00:00 from the daye ?  thanks

Comment: ok its done  with  java.sql.Date ts = new java.sql.Date(todaysDate.parse(date));   thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `Date` object just represents a point in time and has no notion of a format (or time zone). If you print out a `Date` object it first converts it to a `String` using the default formatting of `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy`. If you want a specific formatting when you print it or otherwise represent it as a `String`, you'll need to use a formatter just like you already have.

Comment: Actually i Want to save this date in MYSQL ,where my column is in type DATE/TIME.   so for this i cant send the date in string ,(having exception), i have to send the date in DATE type with the desired format , any solution?

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem here, you have a Date representing and can save it into the DB as it is now. If you print it to the console it gets formatted according the default rules, this is why you think it is different from what you need, but it has actually already the right value.

So just go ahead and put it into your DB.

Chances are that you DB will hold on getting a Timestamp, in this case you can create one:

```
Date d = ...
java.sql.Timestamp ts = new java.sql.Timestamp(d.getTime());
```

and save this one.

Comment: I have tried again , this is the sql query i have taken from the debug mode : update employercvsearches set lastsearcheddate = 'Tue May 24 00:00:00 EDT 2011',counter ='395' where searchtext = 'programmer'       its that same wrong format and after executing this query it says failed. 2011-05-23 00:00:00   this is the format in mysql , i have just copied from there for you.  isnt it possible to convert the above format in this format as in sql    thanks

Comment: Its done :)  ,ohhh Thanks Alot man ,i applied this line Date d = ...
java.sql.Timestamp ts = new java.sql.Timestamp(d.getTime());
and its done ,Thanks Again,you saved my day